# mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in mysql php

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am using prepared statement and executing

```
$search = trim($_GET['s']);
if($stmtgetproducts = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT s.store_id, product_id, product_name, product_desc, product_price, product_discount, product_views, product_date, product_code, product_category, product_image1, product_image2, sale_id,s.store_name,s.store_username 
  FROM store_products sp 
  INNER JOIN store_product_categories spc ON sp.product_category=spc.id
  INNER JOIN store s ON sp.store_id=s.store_id WHERE MATCH(product_name, product_desc) AGAINST('?' IN BOOLEAN MODE);")){
$stmtgetproducts->bind_param("s",$search);
$stmtgetproducts->execute();
$getproducts=$stmtgetproducts->get_result();
$stmtgetproducts->close();
}
else
{
 echo $mysqli->error;
}
```

Since, I am giving it just one parameter to take as argument and binding param just one that is $search it gives me this error

```
mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement
```

this if form

```
<form action="" method="GET">
                  Search Product: <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Enter product name">
                </form>
```

if I change this

```
$stmtgetproducts->bind_param("ss",$search);
```

then this error comes

```
mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of elements in type definition string doesn't match number of bind variables
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmtgetproducts = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT s.store_id, product_id, product_name, product_desc, product_price, product_discount, product_views, product_date, product_code, product_category, product_image1, product_image2, sale_id,s.store_name,s.store_username 
  FROM store_products sp 
  INNER JOIN store_product_categories spc ON sp.product_category=spc.id
  INNER JOIN store s ON sp.store_id=s.store_id WHERE MATCH(product_name, product_desc) AGAINST(? IN BOOLEAN MODE);"))
```

changed my prepared statement to this

Comment: Remove the semicolon from string and we should always check input parameter should not be empty, $search variable does not empty Query. It seems to ok, everything is right.